# Create read MapInfo using C#

Tags: c#, mapinfo, open-source-gis

I've Mapinfo .tab files (including .dat .id .map) I'd like to read the attributes of the files then may store in a DB or write to a csv (not yet decided).

As far as I can tell, using  MapInfo Pro will give me those attributes.

I'm just wondering is there any open source that will do the same?

I'm new to GIS.

Comment: GDAL utility program ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html can do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to read them not convert to a different type I'm afraid

Comment: Why did you write "may store in a DB or write to a csv" then? What else that is than converting to other format?

Comment: What I meant was read them first then will do something with those attributes which is not yet decided. Essentially, will use those attributes to plot them. For now, next step is unclear.

Comment: You can read data for showing the attributes with ogrinfo. Or open the whole dataset as a map with an attribute table with QGIS.

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I can get the details I wanted from the layer using the ogrinfo -al 
Could you tell me is there a way to export them as a csv please?

Comment: Read again http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and then http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html. You will end up till something like `ogr2ogr -f csv output.csv input.tab`.

Comment: I realised what you said after I commented. I will try ogr2ogr. For now ogrinfo -al boundary.tab >> boundary.txt seems to do the trick. Thank you

Comment: Awesome that command helps! It just doesn't export the linestring. Will figure why. Thank you. You are a star!

Comment: There are some options in http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html, perhaps you want to add `-lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` into your command.

Comment: Genius!! Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. The only thing is that the csv has only linestring but doesn't matter. Can copy those fields to the other one. Thank you ever so much